# How can I stop the auto-printing of ^D when pressing Cmd-D during continuous input?

Tags: python, input, eof

I am trying to ask for input multiple times and continuously ask for input until EOF is triggered by pressing Cmd-D. Right now I'm doing this

```
while True:
    try:
        number = input("number: ")
    except EOFError:
        break
    else:
        # apply operations to foo (example: multiply number 2)
```

Say I type 5 and 6 before Cmd-D, this is the output.
number: 5
number: 6
^D
10
12

For some reason it automatically prints a ^D on the terminal even though I didn't print anything extra. I expected it without the "^D".
How can I stop this from happening?

Comment: The terminal echoes everything you type. You could turn echo off, but then you wouldn't see anything.